# How does Mayfeld control the extra blaster on his back?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In Chapter 6 of *The Mandalorian*, sharpshooter crew member Mayfeld uses an additional blaster that extends from a pack on his back, but, from I saw there's no nerve connection from the pack to his body and he didn't press any button or make a specific gesture to initiate or shoot it.

[image]

**How exactly is this additional blaster operated?** How does it know when to shoot?

Comment: Maybe it has droid AI that monitors his body movements and anticipates his actions?

Comment: There's a *lot* of unexplained tech in the series

Comment: The tech behind Mayfeld's auxiliary blaster was obviously salvaged from [M-OC](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/M-OC)'s 'backpack of tricks'.

Comment: It connects by Plot-tooth.

Comment: plot tooth *claps*

Comment: How is it operated? With style and panache!

Comment: The same way the Mandalorian operates the Rising Phoenix.

Comment: Having watched the episode twice the answer to “how does he control it” is “badly”

Answer (score 5):

In [Star Wars Gadgets and Gear](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gadgets_and_Gear) sourcebook there are many backpack-mounted types of weapons, from Laser Rifles to Grenade Launchers that are operated via cybernetic commands by the character. The Blaster from Mayfeld's back is most likely a similar type of backpack-mounted weapon.

As to how it works, the Blaster arm is probably attached to a semi-autonomous body inside the backpack (like how the  [J-1 semi-autonomous proton cannon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/J-1_semi-autonomous_proton_cannon) works).

This is the best explanation I could find.

[Gadgets and Gear sourcebook](https://thetrove.net/Books/_Collections/Super%20Hero%20Games/Hero%20Games/Hero%20System%205E/Gadgets%20&%20Gear.pdf)

Comment: do we have a community consensus on whether the FFG Star Wars RPG books are canon?

Comment: @NKCampbell I tried searching if the book is canon but couldn't find an answer. Either way, we've seen Madalorians using backpack-mounted rocket launchers so we don't really need the book as the only source.